# Evaluate bash/zsh expressions inline

Tags: bash, zsh

I am aware that it's possible to do stuff like

```
echo `ls` "foobar"
echo $(ls) "foobar"
```

but when I try to do something like

```
diff `pip freeze` requirements.txt
diff $(pip freeze) requirements.txt
```

it fails.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

P.S I am using `zsh` shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `diff` command does expect file names as it's arguments, not strings. Something like:

```
diff file1 file2
```

but *not*:

```
diff "$string1" "$string2"
```

If you want to diff the output of two commands (or in your case the output of a command against a static file) you can use [*process substitution*:](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

```
diff <(pip freeze) requirements.txt
```

The `<()` will redirect the output of `pip freeze` into a file at `/dev/fd[0-9]`. This file name will then getting passed to `diff`.

Comment: I wasn't able to get that working in my `zsh` setup but that worked ok in `bash`. Thanks.

Comment: I tried `diff <(echo foo) <(echo bar)` in `zsh` and it worked. Which version of `zsh` are you using?

Comment: I'm using version `5.0.7`. I get this error `error: /dev/fd/11: unsupported file type fatal: cannot hash /dev/fd/11`.

Comment: Check this: http://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/2xig13/handy_bash_feature_process_substitution_xpost/ Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
diff =(pip freeze) requirements.txt
```